# Applying powerpoint theme programmatically

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am making an **C# application** from I create **powerpoint presentations**. I wish to **apply theme** to my presentation programatically. I have got the theme list using the following code. But how could I get to apply them on an active presentation?

```
String programfilesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
String msOfficePath = "Microsoft Office\\Document Themes 14";
String fullPath = Path.Combine(programfilesPath, msOfficePath);
String[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.thmx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Did you check this link **[How to: Apply a Theme to a Presentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850846(v=office.14).aspx)**?

Comment: yeah @Pilgerstofer, I had a look at that link before, however it is not useful since they are copy theme from one powerpoint file to another one. These theme files are .thmx files stored in the location I mentioned above in my question.


See this code in the link you have shared..

string presentationFile=@”C:\Users\Public\Documents\myppt2.pptx”;
string themePresentation = @”C:\Users\Public\Documents\myppt2-theme.pptx”;
ApplyThemeToPresentation(presentationFile, themePresentation);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a few good examples:

1. [Create PowerPoint programmatically](http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/create-powerpoint-ppt-programmatically-using-c/)
2. [Apply Theme PowerPoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297633%28v=office.14%29)

When *combining those two guides* it all comes to this

```
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Core = Microsoft.Office.Core;
// ...

// create application object
PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();

PowerPoint.Slides slides;
PowerPoint._Slide slide;
PowerPoint.TextRange objText;

// Create the Presentation File
PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

// APPLY THEME - for example Clarity.thmx or 
// anything within Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14    
pptPresentation.ApplyTheme(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Clarity.thmx");

PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

// Create new Slide
slides = pptPresentation.Slides;
slide = slides.AddSlide(1, customLayout);

// Add title, modify content and so on ...
objText = slide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
objText.Text = "hello world";
objText.Font.Name = "Verdana";

pptPresentation.SaveAs(@"c:\yourPPT.pptx", PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

pptPresentation.Close();
pptApplication.Quit();
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: @@Pilgerstofer, Many Thanks for your code but there is a problem.  The second link is for VBA, in C# there is no such API as ApplyTheme. :(

Comment: I just - re-checkes my answer. Worked fine as I posted the code. Copy&Paste and check it out for your own - let me know if you faced any errors!

Comment: Found the problem, I was using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint Dll Version 11 and this API "ApplyTheme" was introduced in Version 12.
Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer what I was looking for, I am sharing full code for the help of others

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

String programfilesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
String msOfficePath = "Microsoft Office\\Document Themes 14";
String fullPath = Path.Combine(programfilesPath, msOfficePath);
String themePresentationPath = fullPath + "\\" + Waveform.thmx"; 
// You can change this Waveform.thmx file to any other theme file to apply other theme.


Application pptApplication = new Application();
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

pptPresentation.ApplyTemplate(themePresentationPath);
```

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, how to get this Document Themes ** path dynamically using code? 'String msOfficePath = "Microsoft Office\\Document Themes 14";'